# When I move my object Adobe Illustrator shows an error: Can't move the objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

[image]

When I drag my selected object it displays the following error:

> Can't move the objects. The requested transformation would make some objects fall completely off the drawing area.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the bounding box of what you're trying to move. If there is some stray object, it will expand that bounding box out to surround that object as well. Then you can go delete/unselect that object and continue with your move.

If, however, you see that the bounding box is only surrounding what you're trying to move with no stray objects and you're still getting that error, then it is most likely a guide point. There must have been a guide at some point that was deleted but it still has stray points on either end way out at the edges of your drawing board. A simple fix for this - as you can hunt and hunt and pretty much never find these stray points - just go to View > Guides > Clear Guides. This will (unfortunately) delete all your guides, but it will also solve your problem in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Object > Path > Clean Up is another possible solution.

Comment: Can you please add some detail to explain how this fixes the question being asked?

Comment: this is the best and easy solution.

Answer (score 3):

I my case, I had deleted a guide inside a group with the wrong tool (direct selection tool instead of the selection tool).

I got rid of the stray points (thanks to [this post](http://chrissagert.com/warning-your-illustrator-objects-will-fall-off-the-edge-of-the-earth/)) using View → Guides → Clear Guides (when inside the group, only the guides from that group will be cleared).

Answer (score 2):

Zoom all the way out Select All and look for stray points. I had guides grouped with an object. Deleted them but there was a point still left that was outside of the drawing area.

You'll have to delete the stray points. Zoom way out. You'll see them. Ctrl+Alt+; will allow you to move and edit the guide lines.

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says. You've got an object or objects that would fall outside the allowable drawing area if you move them the direction you are trying.

Sometimes this can be a simple stray point. Zoom out as far as you can and `Select > Select All`. Then look for stray objects and remove them if they exist. If none exist, try reducing the size of your artwork.

Answer (score -1):

Ungroup them all even the sub groups to fix the issue and copy to a new layer

Comment: Welcome to GraphicDesign.SE! Can you explain how to ungroup and how to copy to a new layer?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution. Check the every object mask. It has very large mask that have to be removed everywhere.